# Can atmospheric pressure hinder a pump to lift water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I have this small submersible pump that ironically runs but not lift water when it is fully submerged. The only two ways I can make it lift water the way it's intended to run is to submerge the pump only halfway its intake and to cover half of the output part (increasing velocity).

I was thinking that air might be pushing down water and when I try to increase velocity it just pushes all the air that was blocking it. Isn't it that pressure is practically zero where the water comes out? What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: At what level is the outflow aperture?

Comment: Sounds like the pump is bad…

Comment: The height is just around 15cm. It probably is bad, I'm trying to understand why covering half of the output makes it work like it should.

Comment: Is there anything in the manual about getting the air out of the pump before starting it? Sometimes trapped air wouldn't let the pump pump water. With submersible pumps it can get tricky to get the trapped air out of it. If I remember it correctly, narrowing the output manifold (like you did) is one way of getting the trapped air out, you just need to run it longer in such configuration (but don't fry it). Manuals usually mention it. Another method to get the air out is to give it a little push: connect its intake to a bucket with water sitting aloft (the higher the better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the pump, but impeller-type pumps (which I believe is the type you got) require priming. In other words, you must first allow water to fill the pump, and sometimes tubing for an effective flow of the fluid. The height of the tube is also important to consider because the higher the liquid, the greater the pressure (pressure is a function of height). The pressure that would be preventing the continuous flow is actually the water pressure, resulting in a back-pressure on the pump.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried connecting a 1meter high tube, and seems to do the trick. When the pump runs, it fills the tube for a couple of seconds before going full blast. From my understanding, when the impeller turns and there's only air 10cm~15cm above the pump, the impeller pushes water while air packet is formed behind the impeller blades. The air naturally would go up, creating a counter force (rotation) to the direction of the impeller. I'm not sure if that's really the case, bottom line is, priming does the job.